# Bartle’s Measure Theory, exercise 6F

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

I would like some help in trying to solve this problem

We have to prove that if $ f \in L_p$ and $E_n$ = { $ x \in X : \vert f(x) \vert \geq n $}, then $\mu(E_n) \to 0 $ as $ n \to \infty$

My work:

We have that $\int_{X} \vert f \vert^p d\mu \lt  \infty$. Then, since $E_n \subset X $ for each $n$, :

$\int_{E_n} \vert f \vert^p d\mu$ < $\infty$ for each $n$.

Also, for a natural $k$ we have that $\int_{E_k} k \space d\mu$ = $ k*\mu(E_k)$ $\leq$  $\int_{E_k} \vert f \vert^p d\mu$

Letting go $k \to \infty$, we have that $ k*\mu(E_k)$ $\lt \infty $ iff $\mu(E_k) \to 0$ (By convention  $0 * \infty= 0$)

I want to know if my solution is correct or if its nonsense.

Comment: $\{\mu (E_n) \}_{n \geq 1}$ is a decreasing sequence of non-negative real numbers and hence it is convergent. If it converges to $l \neq 0$ then $\mu (E_n) \geq l$ for all $n \geq 1.$ This implies that $\|f\|_p \geq n\ l^{\frac 1 p}$ for all $n \geq 1,$ which is clearly absurd as it means that $\|f\|_p = \infty.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good, but you can rearrange the equation to obtain something more recognizable.

$$
k^p\mu(E_k)\leq\int_{E_k}\vert f\vert^pd\mu\leq \int_X\vert f\vert^pd\mu
$$

and

$$
\mu(E_k)\leq\biggl(\int_X \vert f\vert^pd\mu\biggr)k^{-p}\to 0
$$

by the Archimedean Property.